# Upload multiple files using web api in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

[image]

I wanted to make an api call equivalent to the given image (api call made from postman) using WebClient or HttpClient. I want to send a file and a text together in one single api call.

Answer (score 0):

You can save image via api call by HttpClient . here is the code:

**Send file to the API**

```
var content = new ByteArrayContent(filedata);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(BE.Common.ContentType.appjson);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                aPIRequestfile.FileName = filename;
                aPIRequestfile.UserId = CurrentSession.Instance.VerifiedUser.UserDetailId;
                aPIRequestfile.ContentType = contentType;
                aPIRequestfile.IsProfile = isProfile;
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("FileDetails", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aPIRequestfile));
                var ApiRequest = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
                if (ApiRequest != null)
                {
                    if (ApiRequest.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        RepsonseMsg = ApiRequest.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    }
                    else
                        RepsonseMsg = BE.ResultStatus.Failed.ToString();
                }
            }
```

**Receive by API**

byte[] filebytes = Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

you will receive byte and then can save it.